# Reading serial data from arduino: Code works..on re run it errors

Tags: python-3.x, automation, arduino

```
import serial 
from vpython import * 

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com8', 9600)
measuringRod = cylinder( radius= .5, length=6, color=color.yellow, pos=vector(-3,0,0))
lengthLabel = label(pos=vector(0,1,0), text='Target Distance is: ', box=False, height=30)
while True:  
rate(20)
if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0): 
    Data = arduinoSerialData.readline().strip().decode("ascii") 
    print(Data) 
    distance = float(Data) 
    measuringRod.length=distance 
    myLabel= 'Target Distance is: ' + Data 
    lengthLabel.text = myLabel
```

The error on re running the program tells

```
11.85
11.53
13.07
13.43
11.66
16.53
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\golut\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\count\tempCodeRunnerFile.py",
> line 12, in 
> distance = float(Data)  ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

On disconnecting and reconnecting the arduino it works perfectly but then as I stop the program and re run it, it stops running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers were being read individually, so splitting is not required, what I tried doing was, I included an if statement after printing "Data" and checked whether the data passed is null or not, if it wasn't, I converted the data into float. This way it works fine. The problem I was facing was the arduino on closing the program and restarting sent null values sometimes, don't know why, so the error kept occuring as there was nothing to be converted into float

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test your code. But here,

Since on your print you have

```py
>>> 1.85 11.53 13.07 13.43 11.66 16.53
```

You should first split this string into multiple values, since python cannot convert this type of string (with multiple floats) and convert the values into float

```py
##data.split() -> ['1.85', '11.53', '13.07', '13.43', '11.66', '16.53']


data = [float(item) for item in data.split()]
[1.85, 11.53, 13.07, 13.43, 11.66, 16.53]
```

Now you can work with the value you need using list idx

Comment: That was a question formatting error. The op read the numbers individually.

Comment: Hey @MaazShahid have you set the right number of BPS?